# Instalar Scrapy en Mac OS X error SSL pip

Tags: python, macos, pip, scrapy

Buenas, actualmente estoy intentando instalas Scrapy en mi MacOS pero todo son problemas, lo primero que introduzco en terminal es:

```
pip install scrapy
```

Y me devuelve:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
Collecting Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/twisted/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
```

Viendo la consideración que hace de actualizar, lo realizo...

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

Lo cierto es que en el día de ayer estuve haciendo mil pruebas y me devolvía otro tipo de error:

```
"SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed"
```

Pero este último error ya no me lo muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar de instalar/actualizar `pip` con `easy_install`:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

También puedes intentar descargar [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) y ejecutar:

```
 sudo python get-pip.py #Una vez descargado el archivo
```

Luego:

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

Otra opción también sería descargar [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) y extraer y ejecutar:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses virtualenv:

1. Instalar virtualenv `pip install virtualenv`
2. Entrar a una terminal y luego crear una instancia de virtualenv `virtualenv env` donde `env` es el nombre de la carpeta que se generará
3. Luego ejecutar el comando `source env/bin/active` desde la carpeta donde se generó el virtualenv
4. Por último generar un requerimientos.txt fuera de la carpeta env, con el siguiente contenido:
   `Scrapy==1.4.0`
5. Por último ejecutar el siguiente comando en la terminal donde se realizó el paso 3: `pip install -r requerimientos.txt`